# Products are not bein saved (anythin else is): keeps loading/processing

Tags: magento, connection, http-post, magento-1.7

Unitll this morning I have experienced zero troubles while saving products in Magento. But, since an hour or 2, my products are just not being saved.

Magento keeps loading (a popup stays with ‘Please wait’) and my product is never saved.

With firebug, I found that the transaction is aborted. I used fiddler to trace the request, and got this:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close

“ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. “
```

Any solutions? How is this possible, all of the sudden?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Please clean the cache directory of magento and try.

Comment: I tried this, but does not work:( Tried to delete directly from my var/cache folder and try cleaning from admin panel.

Comment: Do you see any problem with indexing? enable error log and check in magento log and see if it logs any error.

Comment: There is even no folder log

Comment: The log folder in created inside var folder. Please make sure you have correct permission so that it can create a log folder in case of errors.