# Product is not getting saved/updated from Magento admin panel

Tags: php, magento, http-post, magento-1.9

It was working and suddenly it stopped saving/updating the product data from Magento admin panel and it keep showing loading please find screenshot. While inspecting the cause of error it response in console is -

```
{"error":false}
<style>
body {border:10px solid red;}
</style>
```

Not able to find what is the cause of error also saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318333/products-are-not-bein-saved-anythin-else-is-keeps-loading-processing) in Stackoverflow but it does not able to solve my issue. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. I disabled mod_secure to resolve the problem.

This problem could be solved in one way:

> **1. Try a different browser**
>
> This fixed the problem for me, as I was using Firefox 3.6 (OS X) to access the admin backend, and switching to Safari 5 (I’m guessing Safari 4 would work also) fixed the issue. I tested this on IE7 (WinXP) and it also worked.
>
> **2. Disable mod_security and add whitelist**
>
> Check your mod_security audit log and if you see entries from the admin backend, have your host investigate and temporarily disable the module. If your issues goes away, ask your host to whitelist your admin backend.
>
> **3. Check your www vs. no www redirects**
>
> Make sure you’re only using one form of redirection, either in cPanel, Magento, or .htaccess. See this post for in-depth instructions.

For more information please see the article http://maxrice.com/magento-fixing-please-wait-error-adding-editing-products-categories/

Hope these help!

Please note, issue appear only when website works under https and when I used single html tags like `<img />`.